# Failed to open connection.Details[database vendor code-17] in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports is working fine locally, but when it is installed on the client's PC it shows a `failed to open connection` error.

It's a Windows application in ASP.NET C# and I want it installed on Windows 10.

```cs
private void getinvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    con.Open();

    SalesReportview f2 = new SalesReportview();
    demo r1 = new demo();

    string s = "select T1.prodnm, T1.mrp, T1.prodquntity, T1.amount, T1.tax, T1.Tax_rt, T2.tottaxamt, T2.SI_Date from GST_SalesInvoice T1 inner join GST_SalesInvoice_Head T2 on T1.invoice_no = T2.Invoice_No where T1.invoice_no = '" + ino.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    r1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "~\\demo.rpt");
    r1.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "DESKTOP-PPIVSIR", "GSTApplication");
    r1.SetDataSource(ds);
    r1.SetParameterValue("Invnum", ino.Text);

    f2.salescryrep.Refresh();
    f2.salescryrep.ReportSource = r1;
    f2.Show();

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do the clients have the drivers for the connection?

Comment: What does that connection string you're referencing look like?

Comment: connection string is for database connection

Comment: which drivers it will require

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data source (e.g. ODBC DSN) is set up correctly and matches the "bitness" (x86 or x64) of the Crystal runtime used by the app. For example, a 32-bit DSN can't be used for a 64-bit app.

Comment: I am using sql server 2014